# How to remove JavaFx Labels which has same object name

Tags: java, oop, user-interface, javafx, methods

I created a java program to create a booking system and I have to create a GUI. In the GUI I have created multiple labels with the same object name. I used gridPane Layout for this.

```
     `for(int i = 0; i< waitingRoom.length; i++){
        if( waitingRoom[i] != null) {
            label = new Label(count +". "+ waitingRoom[i].getName());
            count++;
            label.setFont(new Font("Cambria", 20));
            gridPane.add(label,1,count);
            //styles for a label
            label.setFont(new Font("Cambria", 18));
            label.setMinHeight(30);
            label.setMinWidth(120);
            label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            label.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid inside;");
            label.setStyle("-fx-border-width: 5;");
            label.setStyle("-fx-text-align:center;");
            label.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;");
        }
    }`
```

Now I want to delete all of these labels and recreate new labels but when I try to do that following way:
`label.getParent().getChildren().remove(label);`

IDE show an error "Variable 'label' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be final or effectively final"
anyway, I want to delete all of the previous labels and set again new labels because while this program running waiting list array updates.

Comment: There are no inner classes in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell from your question, but if you are looking to only display unique labels, then your `waitingRoom` array should probably be a data type that doesn't allow a duplicate value. Read the Java documentation on `HashSet`.